# Changing pixel brightness in PIL

Tags: python-imaging-library

Apologies for inaccurate terminology or problem description. I am still fairly new to Python. For an eye-tracking experiment, I need to convert a set of stimuli (flower images) on grayscale and make them equiluminant. I also need to keep the alpha channel of the images, although this does seem to be fairly easy.

For the equiluminance, I currently have 3 steps:

1. Calculate the mean brightness of each image, using the alpha channel as a mask:
2. Compute the difference between the mean brightness of the current image and the mean across all images
3. Add this difference to each each pixel of the current image, and round to an integer.

This is my solution for this problem:

```
# For simplicity, I set this to a constant for now. Represents mean brightness across all images
grandMean = 138 

for pic in myFiles:
    picPath = myPath + '/' + pic
    img = Image.open(picPath).convert('LA')
    
    alpha, grayScale = img.split() # Will use alpha as a mask to compute the mean brightness
    imgStat = ImageStat.Stat(img, mask=alpha)
    meanBrightness = imgStat.mean[0] # Returns mean level of L-channel
    
    # Compute difference between grandMean and mean of the current img
    meanDiff = abs(grandMean - meanBrightness)
 
    # Now add meanDiff to each pixel in L-channel
    grayPx = grayScale.load()
    size = grayScale.size
    
    for row in range(0,size[0]):
        for col in range(0,size[1]):
            grayPx[row, col] =  round(grayPx[row, col] + meanDiff)
    imFinal = Image.merge('LA', (grayScale, alpha))
```

As I said, while this solution does work, it is incredibly inefficient because it has to iterate over each pixel of every image. Is there any simpler way to do this?

Comment: You don't need to iterate the pixels for this, look at ImageEnhance.Brightness and img.filter

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply! I looked into imageEnhance.Brightness, and that does seem to be a much better solution. However, what exactly would be the enhancement factor there? Still simply meanDiff?

Answer (score 0):

Adding N to every pixel is a *"point process"* and is easily achieved using PIL's `point()` method. Example of adding 55 to each pixel:

```
from PIL import Image

# Make a linear gradient
im = Image.linear_gradient('L')

# Add 55 to each pixel
res = im.point(lambda i: i + 55)
```

That makes the first few and last few rows of `im` look like this:

```
array([[  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [  1,   1,   1, ...,   1,   1,   1],
       [  2,   2,   2, ...,   2,   2,   2],
       ...,
       [253, 253, 253, ..., 253, 253, 253],
       [254, 254, 254, ..., 254, 254, 254],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8)
```

And `res` look like this:

```
array([[ 55,  55,  55, ...,  55,  55,  55],
       [ 56,  56,  56, ...,  56,  56,  56],
       [ 57,  57,  57, ...,  57,  57,  57],
       ...,
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8)
```

Here `im` is on the left and `res` on the right:

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can convert the PIL Image to a Numpy array, promote to 16-bit, add 55, and ensure no overflow by clipping:

```
import numpy as np

# Convert PIL Image to Numpy array and promote to uint16
na  = np.array(im).astype(np.uint16)
# Add 55 to each pixel
res = na + 55
# Ensure no pixels exceed 255 by clipping
res = np.clip(res, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

# Convert back to PIL Image
im = Image.fromarray(res)
```

---

A completely different third option is to use a LUT or *"Lookup Table"*. First, make a LUT which maps input values in the image to output values:

```
# Make LUT as list and convert to Numpy array
LUT = [ min(255, i+55) for i in range(256)]
LUT = np.array(LUT)

# Convert PIL Image to Numpy array and apply LUT
pixels = LUT[np.array(im)]

# Convert Numpy array back into PIL Image and save
res = Image.fromarray(pixels)
res.save('result.png')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! the point() method was easy to implement and fixed my problem.